# Alternate way to push case-insensitive to regexp_filter besides (?i)

Tags: sphinx, case-insensitive

If I do e.g

```
regexp_filter = iPhone = Apple Phone
```

it works for iPhone but not iphone or IPhone so I tried:

```
 regexp_filter = (?i)iPhone(?-i) = Apple Phone
```

and I get

```
[Err] 1064 - index Products: syntax error, unexpected ')' near ')    iPhone'
```

I'm able to use () in other regexp_filters for capturing groups e.g.

```
 regexp_filter = (iPhone) (4|5|6) => \1 Model \2
```

So clearly it is not the () but the notation for case-insensitive that is not supported by regexp_filter.

Answer (score 0):

Where does `(?-i)` come from?

AFAIK, you just need

```
regexp_filter = (?i)iPhone = Apple Phone
```